# OpenCV. SpringBoot. Illegal reflective access by nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader

Tags: spring-boot, opencv

I've similar problem like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298293/warning-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-portable-opencv-in), but do not see an answer up there how to clean it. As advised added in dependencies maven-compiler-plugin and maven-war-plugin. It did not help.

my pom.xml:

```html
<parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>opencv2</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.1-2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

an error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader (file:/C:/Users/Roman/.m2/repository/org/openpnp/opencv/4.5.1-2/opencv-4.5.1-2.jar) to field java.lang.ClassLoader.usr_paths
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of nu.pattern.OpenCV$SharedLoader
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

For testing I've copied the code:

```html
@SpringBootApplication
public class Opencv2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Opencv2Application.class, args);
        nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
        System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat mat = new Mat(4,3,1);
        System.out.println(mat.dump());
    }
}
```

and this prints the matrix. But if I take example from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-opencv), it does not provide any result except of similar error. How to fix it? It is my first steps in OpenCV, may be I do generally smth wrong and I need to start from smth else?